# @babel/preset-env not transpile ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I've upgrade my Babel config to v7 and add `@babel/preset-env` package for transpile my ES2015+ code.

But, all ES6 Class is not transpiled. My .babelrc file :

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [
                        "last 2 versions",
                        "safari > 7",
                        "ie > 9"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

I don't understand why, anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: You should also post your input file, the path of the file, the path of babelrc and how you are running babel

Comment: Have you found a solution?